# Why is BeautifulSoup not extracting full HTML from a static website?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to webscrape a Chinese website https://bo.io.gov.mo/bo/ii/2021/43/avisosoficiais_cn.asp, but the code below is not returning the full html text. The strange thing is that the code is able to get me the full html from the Portuguese version of the same website https://bo.io.gov.mo/bo/ii/2021/43/avisosoficiais.asp. What is the problem?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

response = urlopen('https://bo.io.gov.mo/bo/ii/2021/43/avisosoficiais_cn.asp')
html_doc = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'lxml')
strhtm = soup.prettify()
print(strhtm)
```

Comment: How did you know that it doesn't return the full HTML, what are you missing? for example a div with a specific ID/Class?

Comment: to be sure that it _static_ as you said, inspect the page with your browser, copy-paste the source code and save it in a file, scrap the file. With `urllib` you can inspect the response have a look to the status code & co

Comment: What content do you actually need from the page?